# How do you save checkbox state in shared preferences after save data button is clicked

Tags: java, list, android-studio, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have set up shared preferences to store the values of an ArrayList after a save data button is clicked within my app. This part is working fine.

The trouble I am having is that I have a recyclerview adapter which populates a recyclerview with rows. Each row contains a check box which turns the text in that row green when checked to indicate it has been completed.

My question is how can I add the checkbox state to my shared preferences and save that state so when I re-open the app the checkbox is saved.

Save button in oncreate in main activity

```
    //Functionality for save button
    final Button saveButton =findViewById(R.id.saveButtonGame);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveData();
        }
    });
```

Here is my code for my shared preferences in Main Activity (outside oncreate) to save arraylist. How can I implement my checkbox state into this?

```
//Save data when save button is clicked
private void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(gameList);
    editor.putString("game list", json);
    editor.apply();
}

//Load data on app start up
private void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("game list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    gameList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if(gameList == null){
        gameList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create three integers for "On" and "Off" states and one to hold the switch value either on or off. This is how I did mine.

```
int reminderState;
int REMINDER_ON = 1;
int REMINDER_OFF = 0;

switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                reminderState = REMINDER_ON;                     

            } else {
                reminderState = REMINDER_OFF;
            }
        }
    });
```

So in your `saveData()` method, you store the `reminderSate` value in your shared preferences.

And in `loadData()` you check if the `reminderState` is on or off then set your switch according to the switch state.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. What I am stuck with now is I have my button in my main activity but I need to save the data in recyclerview adapter as I cannot access the checkbox within my main activity as it is declared in the adapter class.

Comment: Doesn't really change anything. You just have to declare the checkbox in your adapter class and then in your `onCheckChanged`, you store the state of the checkbox. Try following [This tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022) or [This](https://www.zoftino.com/android-recyclerview-checkbox) or [This](https://demonuts.com/recyclerview-checkbox/) for better understanding. Hope i have been helpful.